# Net Send in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, netsend

I have Windows XP, and would like to send a message to a computer that is not on my network.

I know that I can send a message with Net Send to a computer that is on my network.  Can I send a message to a computer that is not on my network if I have it's IP address?

Comment: please tag your questions correctly.  If the question is specific to Windows tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other machine is directly connected to the internet, as in no router or any NAT in the way, you should be able to send it directly to the IP address.

In most cases this is not the case and you will need to forward port 135(i think) to your target machine.

Also Net Send is blocked on many machines and networks and on XP SP3 turned off by default.

If you can you should look into a more reliable way of messaging across a network.